# Simpson A-35 (framing angle) suitable for this application?

Tags: framing, construction, engineering, timber-framing

Would an A-35 be suitable for the rafter>top-plate connection shown here? Would I need one on both sides of a rafter, or just on one side? Existing structure (grey) is 12'x 18', 6" CMU block w/rebar, located in Central California (seismic zone). Essentially putting a new "hat" on the building which will be a small sleeping loft, want to make sure everything is to code, particularly hardware connections. General advice as to fastener/connection details is also greatly appreciated. (i.e. Would simply toe-nailing into the top plate be suitable? Are framing-angles even necessary for transferring horizontal loads/preventing shear in this instance?) Thanks All!
[image: Rafter/Top Plate Detail]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: You might want to explain what an "A-35" is.  I don't think anyone is going to know that by name unless they are a Simpson salesman.

Comment: https://www.strongtie.com/framinganglesandplates_anglesandplates/ltp4-ltp5-a34-a35_productgroup_wcc/p/ltp4.ltp5.a34.a35

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a framing angle such as an A35 is required to transfer the horizontal roof load to the wall and to resist uplift from wind hitting the overhang. (I don’t think an A35n is strong enough.)

I prefer the H1, but one A35 is acceptable. (Two A35 is not required.) Make sure you Install the A35 correctly by bending the tab so the tab can be nailed down into the top plate and sideways into the top plate.

Btw, the top plate on a masonry wall requires a 3” square washer and I’ve never seen then smaller than 5/8” x 10” long spaced a max of 32” oc in your location.

Comment: 3" sq washer tied into the existing bolts was the plan for TP-Wall connection.  Cores of the existing top  2 block layers are hollow though (rebar excluded), wouldn't be difficult to add bolts where necessary? How about the blocking? I was planning on using a LTP4 Tie-Plate to tie the blocking to the top plate, necessary or no? Extremely helpful, btw!

Comment: @LorrinFrench No, the LTP4 will not work. As soon as you drive a nail into the masonry, it will chip out. I’d try URFP or the FRFP , which are designed for retrofit projects. However, please note that they’re really designed for concrete walls, not masonry. So, you could try FJA or FSA foundation anchors, which are mounted further down the wall, but still designed for concrete wall. I’d be remiss if I didn’t tell you to reinforce the top cell. I’m not sure of the stability of the wall. Look through this...start on page 23 https://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/jg8ztjcq8z/C-C-2019.pdf

Comment: I was thinking the LTP would be nailed into the top plate, which is bolted to the wall, not nailed into the concrete block.  Pics added are of the existing conditions. It’s an old dairy building, probably built in the 1940’s.  Structurally it seems pretty rock solid, thing withstood a 6.5 quake no problem back in 2003.

Comment: @LorrinFrench But did it have all that weight on top of it. Hmmm...I see some of the cells are reinforced and there are anchor bolts in those cells...that’s a big plus. If you can bolt into the reinforced cells, that would be best. P.S. Is that a San Juan back there? I miss mine...

Comment: It certainly didn't have as much weight, it was a 6:12 pitch w/ 2x4 and corrugated metal, however it did support a rather weighty wire/plaster ceiling. Although, I'm fairly certain it was well overbuilt for what it is.  Reinforcing looks to be roughly 50-56" o.c. for the filled cells (there's a little variance because of window/door openings, I'll double check the spacing in the morning). Should be fairly easy to insert a titan bolt or something similar into the filled cells w/o existing bolts.  As for the sailboat (?), belongs to my cousin, could definitely use a little TLC!

Comment: @LorrinFrench In lieu of adding rebar, you may be able to use a 4x6 sole plate in lieu of a 2x6.  That would help “tie” the top of the wall together, even though you don’t have rebar horizontal in the top cell. Btw, don’t forget you need an egress window of 5.7 square feet with a minimum of 20” wide opening and 24” high opening in all “sleeping rooms”.   P.S. They all need TLC.

Comment: So after double-checking this morning, there IS in fact horizontal rebar across the top cell, and above window/door headers.  However, top cells were left open, so I'm assuming I'll need to infill that w/ pea gravel concrete. I also found some additional vertical rebar between the existing bolts, same condition open top cell.  Would actually be real easy to add some new bolts.  I'll get some pictures and start a new thread, there are some cracks that have me a little concerned, there's clearly some level of settling that has occurred.  Operable skylights in the loft are 24"x36".

Comment: I do like the idea of using a 4x6, assuming it'd need to be pressure treated?

Comment: @LorrinFrench The reinforcing at the top of the wall doesn’t have to be be in the very very top cell. I wouldn’t fill the remaining cells with gravel...that just adds weight without strength. Remember, light walls (like wood) do better than heavy walls (like concrete and masonry) during an earthquake. Yes, the 4x6 needs to be pressure treated, because it’s touching concrete or masonry. Your egress skylights work fine, but they can’t be no more than 42” off the floor. (So many regulations...why does anyone build?)

Comment: Hmmm...that might be 44” to sill.

Comment: I know right?! This is all the fun stuff they didn’t bother teaching in undergrad, and for significantly less than the cost grad school I’ll have a house instead of a piece of paper to show for it! Basically this project is gonna be be the centerpiece of my portfolio, hopefully leading to some career opportunities. Egress shouldn’t be an issue at all, the entire building is only 12’x18’, 8’ walls.  The loft itself is only 6’ or so to the ridge, roughly 8’x8’ floor area. It’s basically gonna have room for a bed to climb up to, more akin to a camping trailer than a room.